# How do I summarize a value according to multiple columns in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, pivot-table

Summing a column according to one other column is quite easy with a Pivot table. However, it doesn't seem to be possible with multiple columns.

Similar to R's group by, I want to summarize one value (in my case `min`) when values in multiple columns are the same. In essence, I want to convert the following table

[image: table 1]

into this table (here, using `sum`):

[image: table 2]

How do I do that, either using Pivot Tables or formulas?

Answer (score 0):

Putting Column 2 and Column 3 in to "Columns" of the pivot table fields and having Column 1 in "Values" as "sum of" seems to produce what you're asking for - see below example;

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKiZp.png)

Answer (score 0):

*Using Helper Data solves the issue:*

[image]

- Enter formula in cell `G36` & fill it down.:

  ```
  =IF(AND(E36="A",F36="C"),1,IF(AND(E36="A",F36="D"),2,IF(AND(E36="B",F36="D"),3,IF(AND(E36="B",F36="E"),4,""))))
  ```

---

- An array (CSE) formula in `G47`:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($G$36:$G$45, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($G$46:G46, $G$36:$G$45), 0)),"")}
  ```
- *Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill it down.*

---

- Enter formula in cell `E47`:

  ```
    =IFERROR(INDEX(E$36:E$45,MATCH($G47,$G$36:$G$45,0)),"")
  ```
- *Drag formula Right then Down*
- Below shown formula will filled in cells `F47:F50`:

*`=IFERROR(INDEX(F$36:F$45,MATCH($G47,$G$36:$G$45,0)),"")`*

---

- The final formula in cell `D47`:

  ```
  =IF(SUMPRODUCT((E$36:E$45=E47)*(F$36:F$45=F47),D$36:D$45)=0,"",SUMPRODUCT((E$36:E$45=E47)*(F$36:F$45=F47),D$36:D$45))
  ```
- *Fill formula down*

**N.B.**

- *For neatness later on you may hide helper Data (`Col G`), then your data will looks like show below.*

[image]

- *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*